# Solving Laplace's equation for PDE problem: Contradiction Between Fourier Analysis and Instructor's Solution? Confusion with How to Proceed.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I am told to find a general solution for the following PDE (partial differential equation):

> $\dfrac{\partial^2{u}}{\partial{x}^2} + \dfrac{\partial^2{u}}{\partial{y}^2} = 0, u(x, 0) = 0, u(x,2) = 0, u(0, y) = 0$, and $u(3, y) = \begin{cases} 
>       y, & 0 \le y \le 1 \\
>       2 - y, & 1 \le y \le 2 
>    \end{cases}$

I understand that this type of PDE is Laplace's equation, and I know how to go about solving Laplace's equation.

For the sake of clarity and completeness, I will type out my full solution to the problem. However, if you are only interested in the specific problem that I have encountered, please scroll to the bottom of my solution, where I have indicated in **bold text** the beginning of my problem.

---

**My Solution**

$\\$

Using the **separation of variables** method for solving PDEs, the solution will be of the form $u(x,t) = X(x)Y(y)$.

$\therefore X''Y + Y''X = 0$

$\therefore \dfrac{X''}{X} = \lambda = -\dfrac{-Y''}{Y}$

$\therefore X'' - \lambda X = 0$ and $Y'' + \lambda Y = 0$ are the two homogeneous differential equations that we are looking for (as part of the separation of variables procedure).

$\\$

We now first use the boundary condition for $Y$:

$u(x, 0) = 0, u(x, 2) = 0$

$u(x, 0) = X(x)Y(y)$

$= 0$

$\therefore Y(0) = 0$

$u(x, 2) = X(x)Y(2)$

$= 0$

$\therefore Y(2) = 0$

$\\$

We can now begin solving $Y'' + \lambda Y = 0$

$r^2 + \lambda = 0$ *This is the auxiliary equation*

$\implies r = \pm \sqrt{-\lambda}$

The three possibilities are $\lambda = 0, \lambda > 0,$ and $\lambda < 0$.

Skipping to $\lambda > 0$, we let $\lambda = \beta^2$ *Since $\beta^2$ is always positive.*

$r = \pm i \beta$ *From the auxiliary equation*

$\therefore Y(y) = A\cos(\beta y) + B \sin(\beta y)$

$Y(0) = A$

$= 0$

$Y(2) = B\sin(2\beta)$

$= 0$

$\therefore \beta = n \dfrac{\pi}{2} \forall n \in \mathbb{N}^+$.

$\therefore \beta^2 = n^2 \dfrac{\pi^2}{4} = \lambda_n$ is the corresponding eigenvalue of the eigenfunction $Y(y) = B \sin \left( n \dfrac{\pi}{2} y \right)$.

$\\$

We now find the solution for $X'' - \lambda X = 0$.

$X'' - \lambda X = 0$

$r^2 - \lambda = 0$ *Auxiliary equation*

$\implies r = \pm \sqrt{\lambda}$

We had that $\beta^2 = n^2 \dfrac{\pi^2}{4} = \lambda_n \forall n \in \mathbb{N}^+$.

$\therefore r = \pm \sqrt{n^2 \dfrac{\pi^2}{4}}$

$= \pm n \dfrac{\pi}{2}$

$\therefore X(x) = Ae^{n \dfrac{\pi}{2} x} + Be^{-n \dfrac{\pi}{2} x}$

$\\$

Therefore, the general solution to the PDE is

$u(x, t) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} B \left( -e^{n \dfrac{\pi}{2} x} + e^{-n \dfrac{\pi}{2} x} \right) \sin \left( n \dfrac{\pi}{2} y \right)$

$\\$

**!!!Here is where I'm having problems!!!**

We can now fit the other boundary condition.

$u(3, y) = \begin{cases} 
      y, & 0 \le y \le 1 \\
      2 - y, & 1 \le y \le 2 
   \end{cases}$

We found the general solution to the PDE to be

$u(x, t) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} B \left( -e^{n \dfrac{\pi}{2} x} + e^{-n \dfrac{\pi}{2} x} \right) \sin \left( n \dfrac{\pi}{2} y \right)$

$\therefore u(3, y) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} B \left( -e^{n \dfrac{3\pi}{2}} + e^{-n \dfrac{3\pi}{2}} \right) \sin \left( n \dfrac{\pi}{2} y \right)$

Note that this is a Fourier sine series, where the Fourier coefficient $b_n = B \left( -e^{n \dfrac{3\pi}{2}} + e^{-n \dfrac{3\pi}{2}} \right)$.

Our goal here is to find $b_n$. We can do this using the [formula for the coefficient of a Fourier sine series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#Definition):

$b_n = \dfrac{2}{P} \int_{x_0}^{x_0 + P} f(x) \sin \left( \dfrac{2 \pi n x}{P} \right) \ dx$,

where $P$ is the periodicity of the series.

Since our general solution for the PDE has the term $\sin \left( n \dfrac{\pi}{2} y \right)$, we must have $P = 4$, right?

**However**, the instructor has written

$B \left( -e^{n \dfrac{3\pi}{2}} + e^{-n \dfrac{3\pi}{2}} \right) = \int^1_0 y \sin \left( \dfrac{n\pi y}{2} \right) \ dy + \int_1^2 (2-y) \sin \left( \dfrac{n\pi y}{2} \right) \ dy$

The instructor's solution seems to maintain a period of $P = 4$ since it has $\sin \left( \dfrac{n\pi y}{2} \right)$.

Based on my understanding of Fourier series and how it applies to this situation, I am confused as to what is going on here. Recall the formula for the Fourier coefficient $b_n$ (as shown above). According to it, we should have

$B \left( -e^{n \dfrac{3\pi}{2}} + e^{-n \dfrac{3\pi}{2}} \right) = \int^{x_0 + 4}_{x_0} y \sin \left( \dfrac{n\pi y}{2} \right) \ dy + \int^{x_0 + 4}_{x_0} (2-y) \sin \left( \dfrac{n\pi y}{2} \right) \ dy$

**But instead, the instructor has used the limits of the boundary condition as the limits of integration, whilst *simultaneously* using a period of $P = 4$ in $\sin \left( \dfrac{n\pi y}{2} \right)$ ?**
In other words, the instructor's solution has $P = 1$ in $x_0 + P$ for the limits of integration and $P = 4$ in $\sin \left( \dfrac{2 \pi n x}{P} \right)$.

I'm awfully confused as to the correct way to proceed here. There seems to be a contradiction between the formula for the Fourier coefficient $b_n$ and the instructor's solution.

---

I apologise for the long post. I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify my confusion and explain the correct way to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the "having problem zone" $u(x,y)$ is
$$u(x,y) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} B_{n} \, \sinh\left(\frac{n \pi \, x}{2}\right) \, \sin\left(\frac{n \pi \, y}{2}\right).$$

Now let
$$C_{n} = B_{n} \, \sinh\left(\frac{3 n \pi }{2}\right)$$
to obtain
$$u(3,y) = f(y) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} C_{n} \sin\left(\frac{n \pi \, y}{2}\right)$$
which leads to the Fourier coefficients found by use of [Paul's Online Math Notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/FourierSineSeries.aspx), where, for $0 \leq y \leq L$,
$$C_{n} = \frac{2}{L} \, \int_{0}^{L} f(y) \, \sin\left(\frac{n \pi y}{L}\right) \, dy,$$
and leads to, for this problem with $L=2$, $0 \leq y \leq 2$,
$$C_{n} = \frac{2}{2} \, \int_{0}^{2} f(y) \, \sin\left(\frac{n \pi \, y}{2}\right) \, dy.$$
The evaluation then follows:
\begin{align}
C_{n} &= \int_{0}^{2} f(y) \, \sin\left(\frac{n \pi \, y}{2}\right) \, dy \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} y \, \sin\left(\frac{n \pi \, y}{2}\right) \, dy + \int_{1}^{2} (2 - y) \, \sin\left(\frac{n \pi \, y}{2}\right) \, dy \\
&= \frac{4}{n^{2} \pi^{2}} \, \left[ \sin\left(\frac{n \pi \, y}{2}\right) - \frac{n \pi}{2} \cos\left(\frac{n \pi \, y}{2}\right) \right]_{0}^{1} + \frac{4}{n^{2} \pi^{2}} \, \left[ - \sin\left(\frac{n \pi \, y}{2}\right) + \frac{ n \pi \, y}{2} \cos\left(\frac{n \pi \, y}{2}\right) - n \pi \cos\left(\frac{n \pi \, y}{2}\right) \right]_{1}^{2} \\
&= \frac{2}{n \pi} + \frac{8}{n^{2} \pi^{2}} \, \sin\left(\frac{n \pi}{2}\right)
\end{align}

Put it all together to obtain
$$u(x,y) = \frac{2}{\pi^{2}} \, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n \pi + 4 \, \sin\left(\frac{n \pi}{2}\right)}{n^{2} \, \sinh\left(\frac{3 n \pi}{2}\right)} \, \sinh\left(\frac{n \pi \, x}{2}\right) \, \sin\left(\frac{n \pi \, y}{2}\right).$$

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. I am still confused about the reasoning behind $C_{n} = \frac{2}{2} \, \int_{0}^{2} f(y) \, \sin\left(\frac{n \pi \, y}{2}\right) \, dy$. Since we have $ \sin\left(\frac{n \pi \, y}{2}\right) $, doesn't this imply that the period $P = 4$ in $\sin\left(\frac{n \pi \, y}{2}\right)$, since the formula for the Fourier coefficient is $b_n = \dfrac{2}{P} \int_{x_0}^{x_0 + P} f(x) \sin \left( \dfrac{2 \pi n x}{P} \right) \ dx$? But then again, you've got $P = 2$ in $\frac{2}{2} \, \int_{0}^{2}$? Isn't this a contradiction? What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @ThePointer I have made an edit to include the half-range Fourier Sine series coefficient. In the case of this problem the period is 2, as defined by the boundary conditions of the variable $y$, ie $0 \leq y \leq 2$.

Comment: If we reverse engineer $C_{n} = \frac{2}{L} \, \int_{0}^{L} f(y) \, \sin\left(\frac{n \pi y}{L}\right) \, dy$, we get (according to Paul's Online Math Notes) $C_{n} = \frac{1}{L} \, \int_{-L}^{L} f(y) \, \sin\left(\frac{n \pi y}{L}\right) \, dy$. This assumes $P = 2L \implies L = P/2$. Therefore, if $P = 4$, then $L = 2$. Therefore, we have that $C_{n} = \frac{1}{2} \, \int_{-2}^{2} f(y) \, \sin\left(\frac{n \pi y}{2}\right) \, dy$. Could it be that there's something wrong with Wikipedia's formula or that I'm interpreting it incorrectly? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#Definition

Comment: @ThePointer the last note would be valid if the range of $y$ was $-2 \leq y \leq 2$ which is not the case of the problem proposed.

Comment: Ahh, I understand now. This article also discusses this: https://en.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?title=Signals_and_Systems/Fourier_Series&oldid=2951391&diff=cur&diffonly=0#Calculations

Comment: Thank you very much for the assistance!